# What's wrong with my implementation of filter function on matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I am implementing a function named `filter_fir` on matlab, referencing the built-in function `filter` in matlab.

```
function y = filter_fir(b, a, x)

    y = conv(b, x);             
    y = y(1:length(x));                
    as = [0 a(2:end)];
    a1 = a(1);                        
    if a1 == 0
        error('a(1) cannot be zero'); 
    end
    ya = y
    for n = 1:(length(x))
        ya = conv(ya, as);
        ya = ya(1:length(x));
        y = y - ya;
    end
    y = y ./ a1;
end
```

Here are the results:

```
Yt = filter([1 1 1], 1, [1 2 3 4 5])
Ys = filter_fir([1 1 1], 1, [1 2 3 4 5])

Yt =

 1     3     6     9    12


Ys =

 1     3     6     9    12 


Yt = filter([1 1 1], [2 2], [1 2 3 4 5])
Ys = filter_fir([1 1 1], [2 2], [1 2 3 4 5])

Yt =

0.5000    1.0000    2.0000    2.5000    3.5000


Ys =

0.5000    0.5000   -2.0000  -11.5000  -35.0000
```

When a=1，two results from the built-in filter function and filter_fir are the same.
But when a = [2 2], they are not the same.
Could anybody tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: You should *not* call your function `filter_fir` if it's usable with arbitrary recursive parts (i.e. `a!=1`), because in the general case, those are IIRs, not FIRs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry..I am a new learner on matlab..According to you ,when I want to design a FIR, the variable `a` should always be 1?

Comment: that is not a matlab question, but a general DSP question. But yes, please read wikipedia on FIRs and IIRs, and read the matlab documentation on what `a` and `b` are.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK. Thank you very much!